# CSS Transition for only one type of transform?

Tags: css, transform, transition

Is it possible to animate (using transitions) only one type of css transform?

I have css:

```
cell{
  transform: scale(2) translate(100px, 200px);
  transition: All 0.25s;  
}
```

Now, I want only scale to be animated.
In this case I could use position:absolute and left/right properties but I far as I remember, translate() is much better in performance.
I would also like to avoid using additional html elements.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6UE28/2/

Comment: On what event are you transitioning? If only one of the `transform` properties changes between states then only that property (the one that changes) will animate (visibly).

Comment: Please provide jsFiddle

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes! Now you can, because `translate`, `scale` and `rotate` have been moved to a separate css properties! (MDN: [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/translate), [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scale), [rotate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/rotate))

So now you can do:

```css
div{
   scale: 1;
   translate: 0;

   transition: scale 0.4s;
}

div.clicked{
   scale: 2;
   translate: 100px 200px; 
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bjkdthr5/1/ (only `scale` will animate)

Answer (score 45):

**No!** you cannot use `transition` only for certain value of `transform` like `scale(2)`.

One possible solution would be as follows: *(sorry, you have to use additional html)*

### HTML

```
<div class="scale">
<div class="translate">
Hello World
</div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div.scale:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
    transition: transform 0.25s;
}
div.scale:hover div.translate {
    transform: translate(100px,200px);
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Yes! You separate it into two selectors, one of them with `transition: none`, then trigger CSS reflow in between to apply the change (otherwise it will be considered as one change and will transition).

```js
var el = document.getElementById('el');
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  el.classList.add('enlarged');
  el.offsetHeight; /* CSS reflow */
  el.classList.add('moved');
});
```

```css
#el { width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: black; border-radius: 100%; }
#el.enlarged { transform: scale(2); transition: none; }
#el.moved { transform: scale(2) translate(100px); transition: transform 3s; }
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```

Comment: "dont do this" shouldn't ever be a blanket statement in regards to performance. Consider what is on screen, how much is being repainted, what the actual performance impact is, how visible it is, and whether the functionality presented and user experience outweigh the performance impact.

Comment: can you do it in a hover effect

Comment: Also @notrota the DOM is being repainted multiple times depending on frames-per-second during the transition.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, why not.  In order to do that, you have to *actually* use only one transform.

This is what is confusing you: you don't apply transform on the element itself. You apply that to the change-state (by means of a pseudo class like `:hover` or another class using styles that you want in the changed state). Please see @David's comment on your question. You change state for only that property which you want to change and that will animate.

So, effectively you change them selectively based on changed-state.

***Solution 1***: Using Javascript (based on the fiddle you provided in your question)

*Demo*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6UE28/4/

*Relevant CSS*:

```
div{   
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    /* do NOT specify transforms here */
}
```

*Relevant jQuery*:

```
$('...').click(function(){
    $("#trgt").css({
        "-webkit-transform": "scale(0.5)"
    });
});

// OR 

$('...').click(function(){
    $("#trgt").css({
        "-webkit-transform": "translate(100px, 100px)"
    });
});

// OR

$('...').click(function(){
    $("#trgt").css({
        "-webkit-transform": "scale(0.5) translate(100px, 100px)"
    });
});
```

***Solution 2***: Using CSS Only

*Demo 2*: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4pPSw/1/

*Relevant CSS*:

```
div{   
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    /* do NOT specify transforms here */
}

div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
}

/* OR */

div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
}

/* OR */

div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) translate(100px, 100px);
}
```

Comment: Whaat! Downvoter, care to comment what's wrong with this old answer?

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I am personally very fond of doing this. But there are edge cases in which this has undesirable effect. One of them is sprite. If you apply transition all on sprite, the background image will slide.

Comment: Actually there is a fix for my case. Just include `transition: transform` instead of all. +1. Your css way is the recommended way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of forcing a [reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27637245/1911755), you can instead use `setTimeout`.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('el');
el.addEventListener('click', function() {
  el.classList.add('enlarged');
  setTimeout(function() {el.classList.add('moved');})
});
```

```css
#el { width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: black; border-radius: 100%; }
#el.enlarged { transform: scale(2); transition: none; }
#el.moved { transform: scale(2) translate(100px); transition: transform 3s; }
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```