# What is DOM reflow?

Tags: html, css, dom, visibility, reflow

I was reading about the difference between two CSS properties `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` and encountered the **DOM reflow** term.

The statement was

> `display: none` causes a DOM reflow whereas `visibility: hidden` does not.

So my question is:

#### What is DOM reflow and how does it work?

Comment: visibility: hidden keep object in space, so the browser has no need to recalculate dom element position

Comment: Simply said, DOM Reflow is when your browser needs to recalculate the position/size of you DOM elements in order to display a page. In your specific example, you probably noticed that a `visibility: hidden` element seems to still be there (the space needed to show it is still taken, it is still "in the flow", just invisible) while a `display: none` element takes your element completely out of the flow.

Comment: I came here by seeing the exact statement.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

> A **reflow** computes the layout of the page.  A reflow on an element recomputes the dimensions and position of the element, and it also triggers further reflows on that element’s children, ancestors and elements that appear after it in the DOM.  Then it calls a final repaint.  Reflowing is very expensive, but unfortunately it can be triggered easily.
>
> Reflow occurs when you:
>
> - insert, remove or update an element in the DOM
> - modify content on the page, e.g. the text in an input box
> - move a DOM element
> - animate a DOM element
> - take measurements of an element such as offsetHeight or getComputedStyle
> - change a CSS style
> - change the className of an element
> - add or remove a stylesheet
> - resize the window
> - scroll

For more information, please refer here: [Repaints and Reflows: Manipulating the DOM responsibly](https://sites.google.com/site/getsnippet/javascript/dom/repaints-and-reflows-manipulating-the-dom-responsibly)

Comment: animating a DOM element not necessarily trigger reflow, for eg. if you are using CSS3 property to transform, reflow doesn't happen

Comment: Changing `visibility` to `none` is not a CSS style change?

Comment: @Qwerty There are lots of style changes, which can cause reflow, so I guess that's why they are saying "change a CSS style" globally.

Comment: What about adding a CSS variable as inline style? e.g. `<html style="--vh: 98px">`

Answer (score 17):

> Reflow is the name of the web browser process for re-calculating the
>   positions and geometries of elements in the document, for the purpose
>   of re-rendering part or all of the document.

https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow

`display:none` hide the `div` as if the `div` is not rendered whereas `visibility:hidden` only hides but the space is still occupied

Answer (score 2):

It means, that if you will set `display: none;`, your browser will recalculate positions of DOM elements, if visibility: hidden; - not. Think, it because `visibility: hidden;` does not change element sizes in DOM.