# Best syntactique javascript for max-width detect / function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Today I have a question for the best syntax on Js :

Here is the usual version

```
function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 960) {
        $('. slect span').click(function () {
            $('.home-footer').toggleClass('open-in-mob');
        });
    } else {
        $('.home-footer').removeClass('open-in-mob');
        $('. slect span').click(function () {
            $('.home-footer').toggleClass('open-in-mob');
        });
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(resize);
    resize();
});
```

And here here is an other version that works, but, I would have your opinion:

```
if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width:959px)').matches) {
    $(".slect span").click(function(event) {
        $(this).parents(".home-footer").addClass("open-in-mob");
    });
}
```

If you think that an other syntax is better, please share :) 
thanks

Comment: Whats `matchMedia` ?!

Comment: @JonasW.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Something I found here : https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/
https://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1500-matchmedia-javascript-media-queries.html

Comment: It's entirely up to you. If you only need to support browsers [that support `matchMedia`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia) and you prefer to use it, use it. If you don't, don't. But note that **both** your code snippets have the problem that as the window width changes, they register and re-register click handlers, which is a classic error. Also note that your selectors in the first block are invalid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks 
Yes right, selector was just to illustrate my question. 

Ok, any other way to do same thing but little better ?

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier/simplified by using CSS media queries. Adding JS into the mix to control page layouts should be used as a last resort. The more times you have a [DOM reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637184/what-is-dom-reflow) the slower your page speed.

Example with CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
    // Your code here
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Hello @DonCarlos, 
Not good because, I'm adding a function on clic. 
In .css, rule will be applied directly.

OR, I should add my class rules only on responsive view.. hmm, testing..