# Printing numbers 1 - 100 to the screen, extra blank list element added at beginning of li

Tags: javascript, html

Was starting a problem in JavaScript and came across something that interested me. I was starting a problem that simply required printing numbers 1-100 to the screen. I then saw that at the beginning, my `for loop` produced an empty list element.

Was curious as to why this occurred.

```js
//VARIABLES
let list = document.querySelector('ul');


//PRINT NUMBERS 1 - 100 TO THE SCREEN
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
 let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = [i];
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<div class = "container_list">
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**It has nothing to do with your JavaScript. You have an empty, hard-coded `<li>` element in your HTML. Remove it.**

```js
//VARIABLES
let list = document.querySelector('ul');

//PRINT NUMBERS 1 - 100 TO THE SCREEN
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = [i];
  list.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<div class = "container_list">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Now, I realize you are just doing an exercise, but your solution introduces a common performance bug. Every time you update the web page content, the client has to ["re-flow"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637184/what-is-dom-reflow/27637245#27637245) all the content already on the page and ["re-paint"](https://www.learnsteps.com/javascript-understanding-repaint-and-reflow-of-dom-for-increasing-performance/) the UI with that new content. This uses resources. The more you do it, the more resources it takes.

You are appending a new bullet to the `ul` that is already on the page upon each iteration of the loop, so you are causing re-flows and re-paints 100 times with your code!

Instead, you should build the entire `ul` in memory and then when it is fully constructed, you can append the whole thing just once, when the loop is finished.

Finally, [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is for when you are getting/setting strings that contain HTML that needs to be parsed by the HTML parser. If your string doesn't contain any HTML, that's a waste (and under certain circumstances, a security risk). In those cases use [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), which doesn't engage the HTML parser.

```js
//VARIABLES
let list = document.querySelector('ul');
let ul = document.createElement("ul");  // This will hold all the list items

//PRINT NUMBERS 1 - 100 TO THE SCREEN
for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = [i]; // Use .textContent when the string doesn't contain any HTML
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

// Now, append the entire list to the document with just one DOM change
document.querySelector(".container_list").appendChild(ul);
```

```html
<div class = "container_list"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you ! Took away alot from you