# Any alternative to create a dynamic table using JavaScript innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want to create a dynamic table in JSP. The data which has to be entered in the table is coming form an array.

```
var array = data.split("##");
```

I am currently planning to insert table in the div by innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('tableDiv').innerHTML = "
<table><tr>"+
"<th> Exception Id </th> <th> Type </th> </tr>"+
"<script> logic to iterate array and create multiple rows and column 
<tr>... <td>...</td></tr></script>
"</table>";
```

Do you guys have any better way to tackle this? can I remove script from innerHTML string? thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Yes, see [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement).

Comment: @Teemu, Thanks. can you please refer me a code example to go through?

Comment: There are plenty of examples at MDN, when you're digging deep to the table elements creation.

Comment: it's very easy in jquery . First take one variable and append the html code . and assign that variable into css ID. if you want example then tell me I will send as answer

Comment: @user3678149, it will be great if you can help me with the example.

Comment: I have given answer below. Please check

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<template>` a new tag in HTML5. 
 
I don't know the structure of your rows but you only need to write your HTML code of the rows into the template and add some names or classes for the cells to use in a

```
document.querySelector();
```

using a foreach with your array and the template you can append child nodes into the tbody of your table. in the link below explain better who to use templates.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the need to generate HTML in a string and then add it manually to the page by manipulating the [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement) directly via JavaScript.

1. When you invoke [`HTMLTableElement#insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/insertRow) you add a new [HTMLTableRowElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement)
2. Calling [`HTMLTableRowElement#insertCell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell) adds a new [HTMLCellElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement)
3. You can set [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) or [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to set the content of the cells. The results are the same - both are options.

```js
// sample data
var exceptionData = [
  [1, "ERROR"],
  [2, "WARNING"],
  [3, "INFORMATION"],
  [4, "ERROR"],
  [5, "WARNING"],
  [6, "INFORMATION"],
  [7, "OTHER"],
  [8, "OTHER"]
];


//how to put the data in the table
var table = document.getElementById("data"); //selected an existing table 

fillTable(table, exceptionData);

function fillTable(table, data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];

    var tableRow = table.insertRow();

    //setting textContent of the cell
    var idCell = tableRow.insertCell();
    var id = rowData[0];
    idCell.textContent = id;

    //appending a textNode child to the cell
    var typeCell = tableRow.insertCell();
    var type = document.createTextNode(rowData[1]);
    typeCell.appendChild(type)

  }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableDiv">
  <table id="data">
    <tr><th>Exception ID</th><th>Type</th></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This works if you already have a table. If you want to create a table in-memory, then you can also do that using [`Document#createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and then add it via [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). I've added [`HTMLTableELement#createTHead`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/createTHead) to showcase it but you don't have to do that. I can't find a way to add `<th>` elements programmatically from the table API, so I'm using [`Document#createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to make them as well - the `<thead>` is a nice addition but non-essential to how a table would be rendered.

```js
// sample data
var tableConfig = ["Exception ID", "Type"];

var exceptionData = [
  [1, "ERROR"],
  [2, "WARNING"],
  [3, "INFORMATION"],
  [4, "ERROR"],
  [5, "WARNING"],
  [6, "INFORMATION"],
  [7, "OTHER"],
  [8, "OTHER"]
];


//how make the table and put the data in
var table = createTable(tableConfig);

fillTable(table, exceptionData);

document.getElementById("tableDiv").appendChild(table);

function createTable(config) {
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  
  var tHead = table.createTHead();
  var headerRow = tHead.insertRow();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
    var th = document.createElement("th");
    th.textContent = config[i];
    
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }
  return table;
}

function fillTable(table, data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];

    var tableRow = table.insertRow();

    for(var j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {
      tableRow.insertCell().textContent = rowData[j]; //create and set the content
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```

Creating the table in-memory and then appending it has the advantage of minimising the [browser reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637184/what-is-dom-reflow) which will occur if you update the table a lot. In the first example the table would have triggered a reflow for adding a row, adding a cell, adding data to the cell and each could be potentially expensive. With a large dataset, it could lead to really bad performance. If you create the table outside the DOM and then attach it, this will trigger a single reflow which, even if expensive, is much better than many times that.

Finally, here is the second example re-written in ES6 mainly to avoid the plain `for` loops in favour of [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loops.

```js
// sample data
const tableConfig = ["Exception ID", "Type"];

const exceptionData = [
  [1, "ERROR"],
  [2, "WARNING"],
  [3, "INFORMATION"],
  [4, "ERROR"],
  [5, "WARNING"],
  [6, "INFORMATION"],
  [7, "OTHER"],
  [8, "OTHER"]
];


//how make the table and put the data in
const table = createTable(tableConfig);

fillTable(table, exceptionData);

document.getElementById("tableDiv").appendChild(table);

function createTable(config) {
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  
  const tHead = table.createTHead();
  const headerRow = tHead.insertRow();
  
  for(header of config) {
    const th = document.createElement("th");
    th.textContent = header;
    
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }
  return table;
}

function fillTable(table, data) {
  for (rowData of data) {
    const tableRow = table.insertRow();

    for(cellData of rowData) {
      tableRow.insertCell().textContent = cellData; //create and set the content
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px black solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok you have array of objects, you want to show data in table right. Then follow below code.

In JSP page write empty table with header.

```
<table id="tableID">
  <thead>
      <th>Header</th>
  <thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

In JS file write below

```
var text = ""
var i;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
 text += <tr><td>array[ i ]</td></tr>;
}

$('#tableID').find('tbody').html(text); // Jquery
```

Comment: Basically, you and I are doing the same thing. you just took an extra variable and then added it by innerHTML. I wanted an alternative or a solution which might remove script code from my innerHTML string.

Comment: Then use DataTable concept . It's give lot of futures also .

Comment: for that I have to create a table first.

Comment: the new edit seems to be optimized, let me try that, will update you soon.

Comment: @Ayush it is not optimised. It's not syntactically correct for a start and even if it was, it does string concatenation which *maybe* shortens the amount of code you write but will likely perform poorly with large sets of data due to the overhead of creating lots of strings. Other than that, it will have the same profile as any other innerHTML solution as it still requires string parsing into DOM