# Uncaught TypeError: xyz is not a function (when calling it from inside string)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Trying to bind the **validate()** function on blur of input as declared inside render function of *class Textbox extends HTMLElement* (Part-A), but getting the below error

> detail.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: this.validate is not a function
>   (but the **validate()** function is accessible when placing outside the call of the function outside string)

**Part - A**

```
class HTMLElement {
  constructor( ) {
    this.value = false;
  }

  validate() {
    console.log('A')
  }

}

class Textbox extends HTMLElement {
  constructor( ) {
    super();
  }

  render( elem_id, default_value, display_name, placeholder, permission ) {
    /*** this.validate() will work here but not inside onblur function ***/
    var string = "";
    string += "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='"+elem_id+"' value='"+default_value+"' placeholder='" + placeholder + "' onblur='this.validate()' >"
    return string;
  }

}
```

**Part B**

```
const ELEMENT_ARR = {
  "text":Textbox
}

class Elements {
  constructor( className, opts ) {
    return new ELEMENT_ARR[className](opts);
  }
}

function renderForm(){
  var ds = {
    "fields":[
      {"id":"f_name","type":"text","is_mandatory":1,"display_name":"First Name","default":"", "permission":"hidden/editable/readonly","placeholder":"Sample Placeholder 1" },
      {"id":"f_name","type":"text","is_mandatory":0,"display_name":"Hellp Name","default":"","permission":"hidden/editable/readonly", "placeholder":"Sample Placeholder 2"  }
    ]
  }, ks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ds)), form_str="", elementor;

  for (let u = 0 ; u < ks['fields'].length; u++) {

    let type = ks['fields'][u].type,
        elem_id = ks['fields'][u].id,
        is_mandatory = ks['fields'][u].is_mandatory,
        default_value = ks['fields'][u].default,
        display_name = ks['fields'][u].display_name,
        placeholder = ks['fields'][u].placeholder,
        permission = ks['fields'][u].permission;

    elementor = new Elements( type )
    form_str += elementor.render( elem_id, default_value, display_name, placeholder, permission )
  }
  return form_str;
}
```

**Part - C**

```
window.onload = function(){

  document.getElementById('formGenx').innerHTML = renderForm();
};
```

What possibly wrong I am doing?

Comment: This is but one of the reasons for my extreme dislike of creating HTML as string in JS. The problem is that `this.validate` *doesn't run in context of your class*. It will run in the global context. Remember, you're just creating text here, there is nothing to link that text to actual object instance.

Comment: Thanks VLAZ, Trying to create a generic form. What would you recommend? (CreateElement??)

Comment: Yes, programmatically create the elements. I'm drafing an answer right now. Basically strings = bad (usually) because they might work *for now* but then you run into something like this or any number of other problems and you backtrack quite a bit to try and fix the entire mess because at that point, it *is* a mess.

Comment: `HTMLElement` is core class in Javascript. When you run the code that core js class may be extended. Maybe that is the reason why can't you access the `validate` method. So, try with some other class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're generating a *string* then appending it to the DOM and only at that point it will be parsed into a DOM element and added to the page. This happens *outside* the context of your `render` method and has no link to either it or the object that created it. Moreover, the event handler is just set to the string `"this.validate()"` which will be executed in the global context.

To retain access to your `validate` method you have to attach it as a handler at the time `render` executes. The best way to go about this, in my opinion, is to just avoid the step where you generate a string and programmatically create the element:

- [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) will create the node
- [`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) can add attributes
- [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) and [`.add()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/add) any classes you need.
- instead of setting the `onblur` attribute, [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add a proper handler as the direct attribute [but note that sometimes you might prefer the attribute.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

This will generate the elements, you can then accumulate them in [a DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) before adding them all at once to the DOM which will save you multiple insertions and potential performance hit because of [triggering reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637184/what-is-dom-reflow).

Finally, the elements can be added via the normal DOM API but usually [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) is enough.

So, we get the following:

```js
class HTMLElement {
  constructor( ) {
    this.value = false;
  }

  validate() {
    console.log('A')
  }

}

class Textbox extends HTMLElement {
  constructor( ) {
    super();
  }

  render( elem_id, default_value, display_name, placeholder, permission ) {
    /*** programmatically create the input element and set all relevant attributes ***/
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    element.classList.add("form-control");
    element.setAttribute("id", elem_id);
    element.setAttribute("value", default_value);
    element.setAttribute("placeholder", placeholder);
    element.addEventListener("blur", () => this.validate())

    return element;
  }
}

const ELEMENT_ARR = {
  "text":Textbox
}

class Elements {
  constructor( className, opts ) {
    return new ELEMENT_ARR[className](opts);
  }
}

function renderForm(){
  var ds = {
    "fields":[
      {"id":"f_name","type":"text","is_mandatory":1,"display_name":"First Name","default":"", "permission":"hidden/editable/readonly","placeholder":"Sample Placeholder 1" },
      {"id":"f_name","type":"text","is_mandatory":0,"display_name":"Hellp Name","default":"","permission":"hidden/editable/readonly", "placeholder":"Sample Placeholder 2"  }
    ]
  }, 
    ks = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ds)), 
    //just a "container" for the elements. 
    //can be cahged to document.createElement("form") if needed
    form = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    elementor;

  for (let u = 0 ; u < ks['fields'].length; u++) {

    let type = ks['fields'][u].type,
        elem_id = ks['fields'][u].id,
        is_mandatory = ks['fields'][u].is_mandatory,
        default_value = ks['fields'][u].default,
        display_name = ks['fields'][u].display_name,
        placeholder = ks['fields'][u].placeholder,
        permission = ks['fields'][u].permission;

    elementor = new Elements( type );
    
    let newElement = elementor.render( elem_id, default_value, display_name, placeholder, permission );
    form.appendChild(newElement);//append as DOM elements
  }
  return form;
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('formGenx')
    .appendChild(renderForm()); //append as DOM element
};
```

```css
.form-control {
  margin: 5px;
  border-style: dashed;
  border-color: black
}
```

```html
<div id="formGenx"></div>
```

The normal JavaScript API tends to be verbose when programmatically creating an element. Libraries like jQuery can actually make it a bit easier at the cost of another dependency, of course. While jQuery is not strictly needed, I'll just demonstrate how programmatic the element creation would work with it for reference:

```
var element = $("<input>")
  .attr("type", "text")
  .addClass("form-control")
  .id(elem_id)
  .val(default_value)
  .attr("placeholder", placeholder)
  .on("blur", () => this.validate())

return element;
```