# Does `window.matchMedia` trigger a reflow?

Tags: html, css, browser, rendering, reflow

When building a page, I understand it's good practice to try and minimise "layout thrashing" or "[reflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637184/what-is-dom-reflow)", when the browser recalculates the dimensions and position of all the elements on the page. Paul Irish has produced a [handy list](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) of the processes that trigger reflows. He says:

> Generally, all APIs that synchronously provide layout metrics will trigger forced reflow / layout.

How come the `https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia` method isn't on this list? Doesn't that involve measuring the window size? Can we use it without worrying about causing reflows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the list is correct and `matchMedia` does not trigger a reflow. All media queries have been carefully designed to not depend on page content. For example, [`width`](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/#width) has been specced as viewport width *including* the scrollbar so that the result doesn't change regardless of whether there is a scrollbar or not.