# Transition only one kind of transform at a time in CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I can't find a way to transition only one kind of transform in CSS.

I have a bunch of images (arms, legs, head etc.), that upon loading need to have a "transform: translate" applied to them so that they are in the right place before I do anything else.

I then want to have, say an arm, do a transition on just `transform: rotate(20deg)` on hover. The problem is that when transitioning, it will repeat the initial translation along with that rotation, but I only want it to do the rotation on hover. How can I make it only transition that one rotation?

In the example code below you can see that I make sure that the triangle is initially touching the other shape, using `transform: translate`. Then I do a `transform: rotate` on hover.  It works, but it ALSO does the `translate` again.

(I suppose if the images could be placed in their right location without needing a `transform: translate`, that could perhaps solve it, but I don't know how to do that either. And It would just be better if I could isolate the `transition` to only `transform: rotate`.)

```css
/* INITIAL PLACING OF THE IMAGES IN THEIR RIGHT PLACES */
img#Arm {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(220px, 100px);
}

img#Body {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(150px, 180px);
}
/* END OF PLACING OF THE IMAGES IN THEIR RIGHT PLACES */

/* THESE ARE THE TRANSFORMATIONS ON HOVER */
img#Arm {
  transform-origin: 200px 200px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

section:hover img#Arm {
  transform: rotate(25deg);
}
/* END OF TRANSFORMATIONS ON HOVER */

/* THIS IS TO KEEP THE LOGO PARTS GROUPED TOGETHER DESPITE WINDOW CHANGING RESOLUTIONS */
section.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this keeps the logo centered on the page */
  min-width: 800px;
  /* Minimum width of your wrapper element */
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 800px;
  max-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <img id="Arm" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCC87.png" />
  <img id="Body" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmzDM.png" />
</section>
```

Comment: Can you fix the links for your images. As of now they are relative and so we cannot see them.

Comment: I suppose showing a simpler example with just images found online might present itself better, so you all can see the images as well. I will try to edit the code for that shortly.

Comment: It might be a duplicate of this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120132/css-transition-for-only-one-type-of-transform

Comment: I haz kode,  I re-wrote the example with linked images and made it simpler as well to demonstrate.   You can see that I make sure that the triangle is initially touching the other shape, using transform: translate.  Then I do a transform: rotate on hover.  I works, but it ALSO does the translate again.

Comment: @PolarisTLX I still don't quite understand what you want to achieve, however, you can use `translate3d` on `:hover` to keep whatever translate property that you have set before hand in place [example](https://jsfiddle.net/12v2r2qf/)

Comment: @Kangouroops That other link provided a solution that worked thanks, which is to add more divs around the images and transform each div individually. 
The solution below by Daniel Ziegler worked the best and is simplest. Though a combination of both may be needed in different cases.
Like another user pointed out it is definitely a major flaw in how CSS3 handles transforms.

Comment: @PolarisTLX I don't know if you need to add more divs, just more selectors.
But I'm glad you find a solution ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're overwriting your non-hover transform value on hover with the rotate, your arm gets positioned to its original position (like when there wouldn't be any translate on it).

As you can set multiple values for the transform property, just also add the translate on hover to it. This will keep your arm on the right position and just rotates it.

```css
/* INITIAL PLACING OF THE IMAGES IN THEIR RIGHT PLACES */
img#Arm {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(220px, 100px);
}

img#Body {
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(150px, 180px);
}
/* END OF PLACING OF THE IMAGES IN THEIR RIGHT PLACES */

/* THESE ARE THE TRANSFORMATIONS ON HOVER */
img#Arm {
  transform-origin: 200px 200px;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out;
}

section:hover img#Arm {
  transform: translate(220px, 100px) rotate(25deg);
}
/* END OF TRANSFORMATIONS ON HOVER */

/* THIS IS TO KEEP THE LOGO PARTS GROUPED TOGETHER DESPITE WINDOW CHANGING RESOLUTIONS */
section.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* this keeps the logo centered on the page */
  min-width: 800px;
  /* Minimum width of your wrapper element */
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 800px;
  max-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <img id="Arm" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCC87.png" />
  <img id="Body" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmzDM.png" />
</section>
```

Comment: This worked the best!!! It makes much more sense and is workable now. Thank you @Daniel Ziegler!

Comment: @PolarisTLX No problem. To get it a bit better looking, you'll have to play around with the transform-origin, but I guess you know that. Btw would be cool if you could accept the answer :).

Comment: I had to google how to "accept" an answer, but I see it meant clicking on the checkmark icon on the left. Done!