# Disabling CSS transition on box-shadow property

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to disable transition of the box-shadow property on a button and enable it at the same time for different property values?

I have CSS:

```css
#btn-more {
  padding: 6px 28px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #c6ca53;
  background: #9e2a2b;
  border: 1px solid #c6ca53;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #9e2a2b;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

#btn-more:hover {
  box-shadow: 22px 22px 0px 0px rgba(172, 76, 51, 0.5), 0 0 0 2px #9e2a2b;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-more">More</button>
```

So obviously I want `box-shadow` with `#9e2a2b` color property to be visible all the time and disable its `transition`. However `:hover` `box-shadow` should still get the transition on `:hover`.

Tried to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120132/css-transition-for-only-one-type-of-transform) but with no luck. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You want to disable the transition of the box-shadow but you still want it on hover? that is exactly what you have now or do you mean `transition: box-shadow .3s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch the order of the shadows in your `:hover` state and the initial shadow will remain constant:

```css
#btn-more {
  padding: 6px 28px;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 36px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #c6ca53;
  background: #9e2a2b;
  border: 1px solid #c6ca53;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #9e2a2b;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

#btn-more:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #9e2a2b, 22px 22px 0px 0px rgba(172, 76, 51, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-more">More</button>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!